# How to number a lemma in reference to the next theorem?

Tags: numbering, newtheorem

In a document I'd like to be able to write lemmas and theorems such that I always write lemmas before the theorem they support and those lemmas are numbered in reference to the theorem they support. I current have this setup:

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thrm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemm}{Lemma}[thrm]
```

For example, it produces a numbering scheme like this:

> **Theorem 1.1.** *text text text.*
>
> **Lemma 1.1.1.** *text text text.*
>
> **Lemma 1.1.2.** *text text text.*
>
> **Theorem 1.2.** *text text text.*

Lemmas 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 would support the following theorem 1.2 however they are numbered in a way that makes them look like lemmas of theorem 1.1. Instead I would want those lemmas to be numbered 1.2.1 and 1.2.2.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

If Lemmas *always* precede the Theorem they reference, you can just add one to the `theorem` counter's representation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,xfp}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[theorem]

\renewcommand{\thelemma}{\thesection.\inteval{\value{theorem}+1}.\arabic{lemma}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{theorem}
This is the first theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
This is the first lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
This is the second lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
This is the second theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```